# SQL to JOOQ translation: type error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jooq

I'm trying to translate the following SQL statement into JOOQ:

```
UPDATE training_content
SET indx = (
    SELECT SUM(indx)
    FROM training_content
    WHERE indx = ? OR indx = ?
) - indx
WHERE indx = ? OR indx = ?;
```

The sqlite database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE training_content (
  training_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  set_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  indx INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(training_id) REFERENCES training(training_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(set_id) REFERENCES sets(set_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The sql statement swaps two indexes and is used to arrange set objects in a list and is called like this:

```
public void updateIndex(Training t, int index, boolean up) throws SQLException {
    updateIndexStmt.setInt(1, index);
    updateIndexStmt.setInt(2, index + (up ? -1 : 1));
    updateIndexStmt.setInt(3, index);
    updateIndexStmt.setInt(4, index + (up ? -1 : 1));
    updateIndexStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Since i'm moving from plain JDBC to JOOQ i tried to translate it into this:

```
public void updateIndex(Training t, int index, boolean up) throws SQLException {
    create.update(TRAINING_CONTENT)
            .set(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX,
                    DSL.select(DSL.sum(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX).minus(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX))
                            .from(TRAINING_CONTENT)
                            .where(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX.equal(index)
                                    .or(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX.equal(index + (up ? -1 : +1))))
            );
}
```

But I get the weirdest and longest error message I have ever gotten in Java:

```
Error:(50, 17) java: no suitable method found for set(org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer>,org.jooq.SelectConditionStep<org.jooq.Record1<java.math.BigDecimal>>)
method org.jooq.UpdateSetStep.<T>set(org.jooq.Field<T>,T) is not applicable
  (inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.lang.Integer
    lower bounds: org.jooq.SelectConditionStep<org.jooq.Record1<java.math.BigDecimal>>)
method org.jooq.UpdateSetStep.<T>set(org.jooq.Field<T>,org.jooq.Field<T>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.SelectConditionStep<org.jooq.Record1<java.math.BigDecimal>> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Field<T>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetStep.<T>set(org.jooq.Field<T>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record1<T>>) is not applicable
  (inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
    inferred: java.math.BigDecimal
    equality constraints(s): java.math.BigDecimal,java.lang.Integer)
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1>set(org.jooq.Row1<T1>,org.jooq.Row1<T1>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row1<T1>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2>set(org.jooq.Row2<T1,T2>,org.jooq.Row2<T1,T2>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row2<T1,T2>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3>set(org.jooq.Row3<T1,T2,T3>,org.jooq.Row3<T1,T2,T3>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row3<T1,T2,T3>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4>set(org.jooq.Row4<T1,T2,T3,T4>,org.jooq.Row4<T1,T2,T3,T4>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row4<T1,T2,T3,T4>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>set(org.jooq.Row5<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>,org.jooq.Row5<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row5<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>set(org.jooq.Row6<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>,org.jooq.Row6<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row6<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>set(org.jooq.Row7<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>,org.jooq.Row7<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row7<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>set(org.jooq.Row8<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>,org.jooq.Row8<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row8<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>set(org.jooq.Row9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>,org.jooq.Row9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>set(org.jooq.Row10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>,org.jooq.Row10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11>set(org.jooq.Row11<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11>,org.jooq.Row11<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row11<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12>set(org.jooq.Row12<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12>,org.jooq.Row12<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row12<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13>set(org.jooq.Row13<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13>,org.jooq.Row13<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row13<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14>set(org.jooq.Row14<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14>,org.jooq.Row14<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row14<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15>set(org.jooq.Row15<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15>,org.jooq.Row15<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row15<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16>set(org.jooq.Row16<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16>,org.jooq.Row16<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row16<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17>set(org.jooq.Row17<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17>,org.jooq.Row17<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row17<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18>set(org.jooq.Row18<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18>,org.jooq.Row18<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row18<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19>set(org.jooq.Row19<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19>,org.jooq.Row19<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row19<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20>set(org.jooq.Row20<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20>,org.jooq.Row20<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row20<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21>set(org.jooq.Row21<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21>,org.jooq.Row21<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row21<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22>set(org.jooq.Row22<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22>,org.jooq.Row22<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row22<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1>set(org.jooq.Row1<T1>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record1<T1>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row1<T1>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2>set(org.jooq.Row2<T1,T2>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record2<T1,T2>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row2<T1,T2>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3>set(org.jooq.Row3<T1,T2,T3>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record3<T1,T2,T3>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row3<T1,T2,T3>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4>set(org.jooq.Row4<T1,T2,T3,T4>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record4<T1,T2,T3,T4>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row4<T1,T2,T3,T4>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>set(org.jooq.Row5<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record5<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row5<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>set(org.jooq.Row6<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record6<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row6<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>set(org.jooq.Row7<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record7<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row7<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>set(org.jooq.Row8<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record8<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row8<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>set(org.jooq.Row9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row9<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>set(org.jooq.Row10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row10<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11>set(org.jooq.Row11<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record11<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row11<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12>set(org.jooq.Row12<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record12<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row12<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13>set(org.jooq.Row13<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record13<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row13<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14>set(org.jooq.Row14<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record14<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row14<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15>set(org.jooq.Row15<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record15<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row15<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16>set(org.jooq.Row16<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record16<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row16<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17>set(org.jooq.Row17<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record17<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row17<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18>set(org.jooq.Row18<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record18<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row18<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19>set(org.jooq.Row19<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record19<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row19<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20>set(org.jooq.Row20<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record20<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row20<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21>set(org.jooq.Row21<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record21<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row21<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21>))
method org.jooq.UpdateSetFirstStep.<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22>set(org.jooq.Row22<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22>,org.jooq.Select<? extends org.jooq.Record22<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22>>) is not applicable
  (cannot infer type-variable(s) T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.TableField<ch.tiim.sco.database.jooq.tables.records.TrainingContentRecord,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to org.jooq.Row22<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22>))
```

### EDIT

This JOOQ code does almost work:

```
update(TRAINING_CONTENT)
            .set(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX,
                    select(sum(t.INDX).minus(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX).coerce(Integer.class))
                            .from(t)
                            .where(t.INDX.equal(index)
                                    .or(t.INDX.equal(index + (up ? -1 : +1))))
            ).where(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX.equal(index)
                    .or(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX.equal(index + (up ? -1 : +1))))
```

But it generates the following SQL:

```
update training_content 
set indx = (
  select (sum(t.indx) - training_content.indx)
  from training_content t 
  where (t.indx = 2 or t.indx = 1)
) 
where (training_content.indx = 2 or training_content.indx = 1);
```

But the part `select (sum(t.indx) - training_content.indx)` does not work like it should with my original SQL code: it selects for both columns the same value instead of switching them.

Comment: A bit of a guess, but maybe coercing the sum to an Integer might work (found the idea and example [here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2902)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is indeed a bit misleading as the compiler seems to be listing all the possibly applicable overloaded `set()` methods. The reason why you're getting a compilation error is because the left side of your `set()` call is a `Field<Integer>`:

```
TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX
```

Whereas the right side is a `Select<Record1<BigDecimal>>` (Note that [`DSL.sum()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#sum-org.jooq.Field-) returns a `Field<BigDecimal>`) :

```
DSL.select(DSL.sum(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX).minus(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX))
```

But the [`set()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdateSetStep.html#set-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Select-) call signature is like this:

```
<T> UpdateSetMoreStep<R> set(Field<T> field,
                             Select<? extends Record1<T>> value)
```

The easiest solution would be to coerce your right-hand side also to `Integer`:

```
DSL.select(DSL.sum(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX)
              .minus(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX)
              .coerce(Integer.class))
```

#### A note on the query itself

Your call to `minus()` won't work like that. You will need to alias the `TRAINING_CONTENT` table in the nested select if you want to refer to the `TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX` column from the `UPDATE` statement. Like this:

```
TrainingContent t = TRAINING_CONTENT.as("t");

create.update(TRAINING_CONTENT)
      .set(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX,
           select(sum(t.INDX).minus(TRAINING_CONTENT.INDX))
           .from(t)
           .where(t.INDX.equal(index)
           .or(t.INDX.equal(index + (up ? -1 : +1))))
      );
```

Comment: I tested your solution and it almost works: I updated my question for more details. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: @Tiim: Would you mind asking a new question instead, I tend to find it a bit confusing to understand your progress and what parts of the question are still relevant...